# PHP - replace all "\n" Occurrences in a string

Tags: php, replace

I am getting a string in my PHP output with lots of `\n` characters which I would like to convert into `<p>` to get a new line characters in html outpot.

I have tried following:

```
strtr($myString, "\n", "<p>");    
string_replace ("\n", "<p>", $myString);
```

Both of these doesn't seems to work. Any ideas what's wrong in the syntax?

Comment: The functions is str_replace(not string_replace)

Comment: searching http://www.php.net/ usually helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$myString = 'Hello\nWorld';

echo '<p>'. implode('</p><p>', explode('\n', $myString)) .'</p>';

?>
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Hello</p><p>World</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! this worked, Ideally, `nl2br()` should have been doing the job but somehow it was not working for me!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `nl2br($myString);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

```
<?
   $string = "Ceci\r\nest\n\rune\nchaîne\r";
   echo nl2br($string);

  /* will output
  Ceci<br />
  est<br />
  une<br />
  chaîne<br /> //*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`nl2br`](https://php.net/nl2br):

```
<?php $new_string = nl2br($myString); echo $new_string; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to do called `srt_replace()`.

Anyway, what good it will do to replace `\n` with `<p>`?

If you want it to be with linebreaks just use `[nl2br()][1]`